# Running Microsoft VSC on RHEL 7.3

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed X11, libXScrnSaver and xterm. Installed the code rpm. Started a local cyXwin Xserver on windows and tested it by ssh -Y to the Linux box and successfully ran xterm.

However when I try to fire up VSC it gives up - any ideas?

```
code --verbose

[41644:0712/162823.650326:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(317)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
[41644:0712/162823.650444:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(278)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
[41666:0712/162823.927754:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(411)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[41666:0712/162823.927854:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(130)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[41666:0712/162823.930147:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(327)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/xxx/.config/Code/storage.json'
    at Object.fs.openSync (original-fs.js:558:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (original-fs.js:468:33)
    at e.load (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:188681)
    at e.getItem (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:188244)
    at e.handleRestarted (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:207211)
    at new e (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:207106)
    at t.create (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:28748)
    at t._createInstance (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:165542)
    at t._createAndCacheServiceInstance (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:166513)
    at t._getOrCreateServiceInstance (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:4:165703)
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/xx/.config/Code/storage.json' }
[main 4:28:23 PM] Starting VS Code in verbose mode
[main 4:28:23 PM] from: /usr/share/code/resources/app
[main 4:28:24 PM] args: { _: [],
  help: false,
  h: false,
  version: false,
  v: false,
  wait: false,
  w: false,
  diff: false,
  d: false,
  goto: false,
  g: false,
  'new-window': false,
  n: false,
  'unity-launch': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  r: false,
  performance: false,
  p: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  verbose: true,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  disableExtensions: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'skip-getting-started': false }
[41644:0712/162824.475316:ERROR:browser_main_parts.cc(123)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
```